# Text input starts to type backwards after a text selection in presence of PDF iframe

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, input

What is the expected behavior?

That users should always type in the correct direction, even in case they do a text selection in that way.

What went wrong?

If I select the text of input/textarea by dragging the mouse from right to left and ending into PDF iframe, then if I start to type, characters are inserted backwards.

[Video example](https://00e9e64bac2b58abaa9d3c878363961c8ba997a982bbc1ad1b-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/monorail-prod.appspot.com/o/16%2Fattachments%2F5df396a3-6adf-47d3-9387-9aa7ea34e937?qk=AD5uMEvt1fc_SyqmjcqtyXEgcbAqbExqpwtxG4SQ8oA1DtjxqfmjohPQpbAJhvGbv5Q7GzvamPZ8UiWYoa71Y19NV-LlKs2SlVSS3TF-YrcSKofsC3dP5YQjVCjqCBywjtzeWB0GTvAR63W2yCz0UJVaSO5Jd0y51piGGKK_JBj5oNLFQCSLwychuIzdbOx_qFKY0jOrU5LUoSGXOY8iKO1yX_CFR_l5gFMTMPR9Tdi0GebEXx-pATeSKs4PtvF2BiMNxhw7h5KaLhXVFGQ0xpRy_kBf9uhN1ylwEdPxuAqnZelmCsMPtBHU_Tn2_oNblKaKNleiLLJT9faDusg5Bd7H729i2G_cucvxmAb223xHotWTFveFwri7IuqX187VoWCle47KU453_xGzIMXEePFrhS8KodeuccIOLD0PempkqTpdPNKvtz2R7MqpBFuiGA5iG1gQ1Pntb4G6ep2GXMi9t3OSRwrXgetJspwJFByl2sCNIq_MIlRPd5b9nqzkBvl6KPq-PDbAAy0OWSMni4CSpN91jfJ8Z9kx6f8_G2oFysEfIKajd1A32KRrUmU0cHBpjY9MYSnonjV5OZ1y6oAwiIeGIiCaMiS9xbE1fsUGhFINXvLeS0Jb7N0_bW0t0NxSWfdakr5niI9WzwN2s3jSaP74--9dVHzxhVnm_VYnwQ1HnvzXHIryjPOaVREzfe04rDB444Ck4RbXvQj7EkWkWH46nlbYYUHAJOKJNUx3kgb6F9OaRvf907E-XrtBbKPgoWTUTtp1bN73wmHoU7avyDl2Saw-0BDSx5AFMXFyxdNU7wuJbfmn1ftBS6GaKoa-qcYBd2zNXJNECvyYKkiLM4hoT-D6wTQwUJjQrJTEQGcPJceRuIM)

Version of chrome:

Google Chrome is up to date
Version 73.0.3683.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Any idea for this, some workaround???

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I have edited it

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be an issue of Chromium-based browsers.
I can confirm it is present in Chrome Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit)
If I hover on embedded pdf then input receive keyboard strokes backward if I don't then everything comes back to normal

Answer (score -1):

It's possible that the PDF is including a special invisible character that switched the writing direction from left-to-right *(the default in English and most other languages)* to right-to-left *(like in Hebrew or Arabic)*

Try highlighting the text in this example:

```
I enjoyed staying -- באמת!‏ -- at his house.
```

in HTML, the character encoding for this is: `&rlm;`

Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark