# How to avoid html input fields typing backwards in chromium browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, chromium

The following code sample when opened in a chromium browser will result in the input field typing backwards (after following the steps below). Are there any ways to work around this unexpected browser behavior after following the steps below?

1. Open the code below in a chromium browser.
2. Adjust the height of the browser window so that the scroll bar appears on the right of the page.
3. Type a value into the input field.
4. Using your mouse, highlight the value in the input field, and release the mouse while over the PDF document (making sure at least some of the input value is still highlighted upon release). Leave the mouse where you released.
5. Start typing. The text types backwards into the field.

```html
    <html>
    <body>
    <input type="text">
    <br>
    <embed src="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" width="900" height="900" >
    </body>
    </html>
```

Note: This needs to be run outside of the snippet view to reproduce the issue.

Here's a video of the issue in action:
https://youtu.be/gcFLcoKExOY

Comment: I can reproduce this in Chrome Version 97.0.4692.99 (Official Build) (64-bit) and MS Edge v97.0.1072.69 (Official build) (64-bit).

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in both Edge and Chrome. I think that's an issue with chromium. I suggest that you can open a new issue on [this site](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list).

Answer (score 2):

**[Edit Update 2024]

This has reputedly been fixed** in Chromium 2024 browsers
After comment = *Verified the fix on 122.0.6185.0.*

I do not see the problem in current Version 122.0.6261.95 (Official Build)

HOWEVER when testing previous January 2024 stable versions (121)
I can confirm the problem was still there in NEWEST MS Edge Version 121.0.2277.83 (Official build) using the test samples in the closure bug report.

This appears to be an intermittent problem report so last time added to bug tracker was Chrome version: 103

**Wed, Apr 21, 2021** With using near PDF see
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1201368

**Fri, Sep 3, 2021** seems similar "near proximity of a video element" see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1246506

**Mon, Jul 25, 2022** most recently suggested as when mouse cursor is above a Google adsense ad.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1347176&q=backwards&can=2

However oldest I found is here on SO
asked **Mar 12 '19** [Text input starts to type backwards after a text selection in presence of PDF iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55131793/text-input-starts-to-type-backwards-after-a-text-selection-in-presence-of-pdf-if)

and was still present in
**Mar 26 '20** https://stackoverflow.com/a/60873125/10802527

Thus it appears to be an ongoing problem for a few years!
What was strange was that I never saw that oddity, even when testing above report until I updated Edge to Version 97.0.1072.69 (Official build) (32-bit) matching the OP 64 bit I am on Win 7 and ***yes I now see the same odd behavior*** (unknown if the reset on rebuild had any effect.)