# Vuejs - Text gets reversed when typing after selecting all

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm facing a weird issue. The text in a particular inputbox gets reversed if I enter a text after selecting all the current text. Please see the image below. I have created a textfield component that is used in the parent component. I'm not sure how to debug this. Tried using chrome inspect tools, but couldn't find anything useful. Also tried using below CSS

```
direction: ltr !important;
```

[image]

The component code is

```
template>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label :for="question.q_question">{{question.q_question}}</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                class="form-control write-direction" 
                v-model="value"
                :id="question.q_question" 
                :name="question.q_question" value=""
                @keyup="handleTextboxValue"
                >
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
    props: ['question'],
    data() {
        return {
            value: ''
        }
    },
    methods:{
        handleTextboxValue() {
            this.$emit('handleTextboxValue', this.question, this.value)
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style scoped>

label {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.write-direction {
    direction: ltr !important;
}
</style>
```

**EDIT** This appears to happen only with google chrome. I tested with firefox and its working correctly.

**EDIT2** I found this thread - [How to avoid html input fields typing backwards in chromium browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70871496/how-to-avoid-html-input-fields-typing-backwards-in-chromium-browsers)

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/15141703/google-randomly-starts-typing-backwards-input-character-moves-r-to-l-instead-of-l-to-r?hl=en

Comment: is it to do with direction: rtl I wonder

Comment: Check with the vue devtool or adding a `<pre v-text="value"></pre>` to see if the value is actually reversed, if yes, then you can remove the CSS direction property and keep on debugging.

Comment: @Bravo sorry it should be ltr. I have Updated the question. I added CSS `direction: ltr !important;` to fix the above issue. But it has no impact.

Comment: @hangindev.com Yes I check with Vue dev tool and <pre v-text="value"></pre> and both case the value is actually appearing reversed. Is there way to identify which javascript code is affecting the textfield

Comment: facing this in angular too but only for one of my text input boxes

Comment: Another thing to look for: you can set the cursorPosition to `$('input').selectionStart` and it will always put the cursor at the front of the text box as you type.