# Jquery input element when focus() is set programmatically cursor blink is not appearing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two siblings divs, left side I am loading pdf and right div I have jquery input fields.

I am trying select the value from input with the mouse and delete it with backspace. When I select the value from the input the mouse hover is on pdf document and now I am pressing backspace to delete the value . The value is deleted and I see the `document.activeElement` is input field but I do not see the cursor blinking. Without this cursor blink if I start typing the value it showing in reverse.

I see its limitation with browser but do we have any workaround for this.

I have tried below options but no luck

1. Get the input element and use inputele.focus() and .select() when backpressed is clicked.
2. wrap the inputele.focus() in setTimeout.
3. use of setSelectionRange
4. adding event buddling and capturing when mouse enter the pdf and when backspace is pressed(e.stopPropagation,e.preventdefault etc)

I have spent so much time googling on this for a workaround but no luck.
Please let me know if we have any solution for this.
Much appreciated.

below is sample code

```html
<div class="container" style="
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
">
  <div>
  <iframe src="https://www.ifpi.org/content/library/DMR2010.pdf">
  
  </iframe>
</div>
<div>
   <input id="inputId" type="text">
</div>
  
</div>
```

[image: image below]

Comment: I don't think cursor blinking should depend on how you set the focus. Can you add a [mre]?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the quick response . I have added the sample code and image of this scenario with DOM structure. I have tried to replicate the same in jsfiddle/codesandbox but these tools have iframe within an iframe and in that scenario I do not see an issue . My case has only one iframe and input field.

Comment: And one more thing here in my case when cursor blinking is not coming and then when I type something in input its printing in reverse order.

Comment: You need to provide more code than only html...

Comment: @SKJ Thank you for the response. I don't have any other logic. Type something in the input box and select it left mouse click and hold drag it till the mouse pointer is on the pdf document and then press backspace to delete. The value will be deleted and focus is still on input box but cursor is not blinking. Issue won't be there if mouse pointer isn't on pdf.

Comment: Isn't this a JavaScript/jQuery question? Post the JS code that's having the problem.

Comment: "I have two siblings divs" Your sample code only has one div.

Comment: Hi @Barmar I have now updated the code by enclosing div's but still see the same problem. I am not using any JS/Jquery yet here, they are just div with  iframe pdf and input element and used the keyboard to enter the value in the input and delete it using backspace ... Do we have any browser limitation for this issue?

Comment: I've made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/uorn6v2w/ What do I have to do to see the problem?

Comment: I have now uploaded the gif to see the effect. And I said earlier in my first comment  " I have tried to replicate the same in jsfiddle/codesandbox but these tools have iframe within an iframe and in that scenario I do not see an issue . My case has only one iframe and input field."

Comment: Hi @KJ Exactly I am facing the same issue. I am using chrome 120 version but same issue. Issue is there in all browsers(edge, Mozilla )What would be the best approach now?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is described best by Chromium Bug report response https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1402816 as

> "A MouseDown on a main frame does not trigger capture, so if you move the mouse to a cross-origin iframe and release the button, the main frame does not receive the MouseUp (it was sent to the iframe's renderer process only). The main frame behaves as if there is still a drag in progress, resulting in some strange things like typing into an input element having the text come out backward."

Reputedly this has been fixed at the end of last year 2023, after many bug reports spanning back to April 2019. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70911001/10802527 However beware it might manifest similar by other means.

The answer is see if a Browser update resolves that bug and the other reported causes.

Comment: hi @KJ.. I have downloaded chrome dev version 123 and I see they fixed this issue. But I think they have not released into actual Chrome version because when I download latest chrome browser I see 121 version. Do you know if there is any open issue with other browser as well like edge,mozilla..